# Is it possible to make a payment request on behalf of another user with PayPal REST API

Tags: rest, paypal

It doesn't appear so from the docs but I may be missing it. I would like to create an application that would provide the service for a user to sell to someone else - think ebay.com - is it possible - with the REST api https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ - for me to create  this. As far as I can tell I don't see any permission/payee entries in their docs but...

Comment: Yashua, have you been able to find an answer for your question in the meantime, as I have the same question myself now?

Comment: @Aleks - Sorry - never found an answer to this.

Comment: Heh, I might have following the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577763/rails-with-paypal-permissions-and-paypal-express-checkout/32869517 , but I am still investigating , but thanks in any case. If I remember, I will post an answer here afterwords