# Rails with Paypal Permissions and Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm building an application where a user can connect their own Paypal account through Paypal Permissions SDK (https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-ruby). I was able to successfully get permission from the user and was able to store the tokens that were returned from the Paypal Permissions SDK. Now, I am using the following gem for Express Checkout (https://github.com/nov/paypal-express). But the documentation for Paypal Express Checkout on behalf of a user is not clear on how we should use the tokens to invoke a call for Express Checkout.

I have the following codes

```
@api = PayPal::SDK::Permissions::API.new({
  token: @credential.paypal_access_token,
  token_secret: @credential.paypal_secret_token
})
```

Where @credential is my object stored in the database that has the tokens from the Paypal Permissions SDK.

Now after getting, I can use the @api object to get Paypal Username, Password, and Signature

```
request = Paypal::Express::Request.new(
  :username   => @api.config.username,
  :password   => @api.config.password,
  :signature  => @api.config.signature
)
```

Now, my problem is that the money isn't going directly to the users paypal account but it is going to our account (we made an account so that we can create a Application in the Classic API part of Paypal).

Is there anyone who can help me? or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling API on behalf of other account, you need to add parameter "subject" to indicate the account that you are calling API for. The value of "subject" could be the account primary email address or payerID. Then the money will go to the account which was the value of subject.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm still a bit lost.. I'm trying to read the paypal documentation and I only see the subject field in the NVP api. Is this what I should use instead of the express checkout api?

Comment: You are right, the subject field is only mentioned in the nvp and soap basic doc, because it's the basic usage of the classic api. This is the field you need to use together with your API credentials when calling any classic API(including express checkout api) on behalf of another account.

Comment: Thank you! your guidance helped me so much.

Comment: For reference - The NVP and `subject` field can be found here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

Answer (score 0):

Yihui gave the right answer. But I wanted to explain/post here what I did to fix my problem (using Yihui's guidance).

You need to get the Payer ID from the 3rd Party Permissions SDK of Paypal. So you will need to ask for the following "ACCESS_BASIC_PERSONAL_DATA", "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT", and "REFUND".

Then you will need to use the NVP (Name Value Pair) SDK of paypal to perform Express Checkout on behalf of another party/merchant.

For more information, we followed the following article of Paypal 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/