# Express Checkout on the behalf of actual merchant

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5.4

I am working on a marketplace site which have multiple sellers. While implementing paypal integration, seller grant their permissions to third party which includes the scope of express checkout. I have implemented this successfully

Though one of the following post I come to know that it is possible through NVP/SOAP API, but it is deprecated.

LINK: [Rails with Paypal Permissions and Paypal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577763/rails-with-paypal-permissions-and-paypal-express-checkout)

Is there any way available for it or need to integrate this only?